# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'. > finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: android, android-studio, compilação, gradle

Estou tentando executar o compilador do Android Studio, porem me retorna este erro.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'. >  finished with non-zero      exit value 1
```

build.gradle app:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.estudosmobileoreia.mpeprojeto"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
}
```

Comment: O SOen tem uma [questão](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/163596/errorexecution-failed-for-task-apppredexdebug-finished-with-non-zero-exi) parecida. Tente adicionar mais detalhes a sua pergunta, como todo o **log** de erros caso haja, vai facilitar para que você receba uma resposta mais objetiva.